# Conditional new column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for example:

```
      B1   B2   B3  B4  BCS ULCA     MIMO 
6    28A   1A             0    .       1A   
7    28A   1A             1    .       1A    
8     3A   1A             0    .       1A  
9     3A   1A             1    .       1A   
10    3A   1A             0    .       3A   
11    3A   1A             1    .       3A  
12    3A   1A             0    .    1A-3A   
13    3A   1A             1    .    1A-3A
```

and I use `np.where` to do the condition as new columns:
If B1-B4's value is equal MIMO then put `4` in new col, if not, put `2`

```
b['B1_m'] = np.where(b['B1'] == b['MIMO'], '4', '2')
b['B2_m'] = np.where(b['B2'] == b['MIMO'], '4', '2')
b['B3_m'] = np.where(b['B3'] == b['MIMO'], '4', '2')
b['B4_m'] = np.where(b['B4'] == b['MIMO'], '4', '2')
```

but my ouput have some mistake at some rows (row 10, 11):

```
          B1   B2   B3  B4  BCS ULCA     MIMO B1_m B2_m B3_m B4_m
    6    28A   1A             0    .       1A    2    4    2    2
    7    28A   1A             1    .       1A    2    4    2    2
    8     3A   1A             0    .       1A    2    4    2    2
    9     3A   1A             1    .       1A    2    4    2    2
    10    3A   1A             0    .       3A    2    2    2    2
    11    3A   1A             1    .       3A    2    2    2    2
    12    3A   1A             0    .    1A-3A    2    2    2    2
    13    3A   1A             1    .    1A-3A    2    2    2    2
```

Is there any hint for what's happing?

---

Update

```
d = b.loc[9:12, ['B1','MIMO']].to_dict(orient='list')
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'B1': ['3A', '3A', '3A', '3A'], 'MIMO': ['1A', ' 3A', ' 3A', ' 1A-3A']}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Images doesn't help!

Comment: check if there are whitespaces around the values.

Comment: I think there should be data different, check it `d = df.loc[9:12, ['B1','MIMO']].to_dict(orient='list')`

Comment: Can you add to question what is `d = df.loc[9:12, ['B1','MIMO']].to_dict(orient='list')` `print (d)` ?

Comment: @jezrael updated in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem is necessary remove traling whitespaces by [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
b['MIMO'] = b['MIMO'].str.strip()
```

Also your solution should be rewrite to one `np.where` with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for comparing:

```
cols = ['B1','B2','B3','B4']
arr = np.where(b[cols].eq(b['MIMO'], axis=0), '4','2')
#alternative
#arr = np.where(b[cols].values == b['MIMO'].values[:, None], '4','2')

b = b.join(pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=cols, index=b.index).add_suffix('_m'))
print (b)
     B1  B2  B3  B4  BCS ULCA   MIMO B1_m B2_m B3_m B4_m
6   28A  1A NaN NaN    0    .     1A    2    4    2    2
7   28A  1A NaN NaN    1    .     1A    2    4    2    2
8    3A  1A NaN NaN    0    .     1A    2    4    2    2
9    3A  1A NaN NaN    1    .     1A    2    4    2    2
10   3A  1A NaN NaN    0    .     3A    4    2    2    2
11   3A  1A NaN NaN    1    .     3A    4    2    2    2
12   3A  1A NaN NaN    0    .  1A-3A    2    2    2    2
13   3A  1A NaN NaN    1    .  1A-3A    2    2    2    2
```